# Get IP camera's picture with HTTP request

Tags: java, http-get, ip-camera

I am trying to reach Foscam C1 IP camera's picture with a HTTP GET request from a java program.

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.6:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2&usr=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The url works perfectly in the browser.

It writes out this:

```
<html><body><img src="../snapPic/Snap_20151008-094559.jpg"/></body></html>
```

How can I get the picture itself?

/////
EDIT:
/////

```
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      line = line.substring(24, 57); //here I get the needed part
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    //This all stuff should go into the loop:
    HttpGet httpGetPicture = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.6:88/" + line);
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGetPicture);

    is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    line = null;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```

So I also make a get request for the img url:
Answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd parse the `img` tag for the picture's URL and make a request for that.

Comment: I don't understand it. The problem is: http://192.168.1.6:88/snapPic/Snap_20151008-103709.jpg >> 404 not found.

Comment: @Fantom789 And you make that request immediately after the first request? And the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes now you see my edit on question. URL looks good: "http://192.168.1.6:88/" + line
where line is: /snapPic/Snap_20151008-104725.jpg

Comment: @Fantom789 When you exit the first `while` loop, `line` is null (it's the loop condition), not the actual URL of the image. Put the result of `substring` in a different variable, don't reuse `line`.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! Now I get something like this: ˙Ř˙ŕ etc.
So this is the picture data right? Now I can make picture from it somehow

Comment: @Fantom789 Yes, that's the JPEG picture data. You need to read it with an `InputStream` since it's binary data.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use other URL params for the image data, see
http://www.foscam.es/descarga/ipcam_cgi_sdk.pdf

also check out this C# article
http://blogs.infosupport.com/writing-an-ip-camera-viewer-in-c-5-0/
that you can adapt if you want to get consecutive JPEG frames as an MJPEG stream. You could easily adapt that code to Java

Comment: btw, note that the article is for Foscam MJPEG models, not the HD ones (the CGI API is different in those). Regarding the PanTilt control part from that article I have evolved it and added support for both MJPEG and HD Foscam models, see http://FoscamController.codeplex.com

Comment: also note that the Foscam HD models seep to support ONVIF (you can set the ONVIF port at the camera settings webpage) - http://www.onvif.org so one could use webservices to grab frames